# Remove name of section from header in pagestyle{fancy} (Notice: document class=article)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am forced to use the document class: `article`, because of several packages that I use and format restrictions.

I have long names for some of the sections and subsections, so there is no room to display it all in the header.

I only use: section-->subsection-->subsubsection, no "chapter".

I wish the header to display only `subsection` names and numbers, not `sections`. How do I do that?

When I use `\fancyhf{}` everything disappears from the header.

I also  tried a solution that I found on this website

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape }
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

... but it doesn't display anything. I think the problem might be that the document class is different than what they had there, but I cannot change that.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you know that you have the right to [edit your own questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296572/remove-name-of-section-from-header-in-pagestylefancy-document-class-article), right?

Comment: Posting a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) is much more effective and obvious than adding ten `!` to the question title. Please post an MWE.

Comment: `15.02pt` as font size option?

Comment: yeah, you're right, thx, that was a mistake of course, but not the source of the problem with the header I think (?).. I will try to upload a working example as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine the commands which fills the marks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{} %section doesn't set a mark
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsectionmark[1]{% but subsection should
 \markright{\MakeUppercase{\ifnum\c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \thesubsection \quad \fi #1}}}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\section{abc}\subsection{subsection}
\lipsum   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great, thx! Quick followup: How do you make the header in this case to appear in small letters, not CAPITALS?

Comment: Remove the MakeUppercase command.

Comment: I'm starting to regret that I answered your question without waiting for your complete minimal example.